# tomcat and mysql memory usage

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, memory-management

I want to device an app which will check the tomcat memory usage and mysql memory usage at any given time.
my question is, is there any way to retrieve these values in java? Please can any one provide me the sample code snippnet.

Thanking in advance

Comment: For Tomcat, search for JMX (Java Management Extension). For MySQL I have no idea.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : if I used the line ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean().getHeapMemoryUsage().getUsed()...   Does this gives me the memory usage by tomcat?